# Dictionary C# (Русско - английский переводчик)

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции, словари

Делаю приложение, которое должно предоставить перевод английских слов на русский.
Так же должна быть возможность записи новых слов в переводчик и удаление.
С записью разобрался, ничего сложного нет. А вот с удалением беда. 
Если я записываю мои слова в ListBox, то как мне вытащить оттуда ID слова (выбранного), что бы можно было по ID удалить ?
Думал при помощи listBox1.SelectedItem, но тут проблема. Если к примеру у меня будет 5 записей, и я выберу 3ю запись и удалю ее, то индексы ListBox и моих в словаре не будут соответствовать.

Вот кусочек кода:

```
public Dictionary<int, string> pl = new Dictionary<int, string>();
public Dictionary<int, string> eng = new Dictionary<int, string>();

public Dictionary()
{
   pl.Add(1, "Czesc"); eng.Add(1, "Hello");
   pl.Add(2, "Ksiazka"); eng.Add(2, "Book");
   pl.Add(3, "Wisnia"); eng.Add(3, "Cherry");
   pl.Add(4, "Samochod"); eng.Add(4, "Car"); 
}

// методод добавления записей

public void DictionaryAdd(string wordEng, string wordPl)
{
    index++; // ??? как тут быть с индексами, что бы не приходилось при                        
             //добавлении записи каждый раз вписывать новый индекс
    eng.Add(index, wordPl);
    pl.Add(index, wordEng);
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам int -> string? Не лучше ли просто string -> string?

Comment: @VladD Согласен с Вами полностью. Это бы все облегчило. Преподаватель так хочет ;)

Comment: @kxxko Передайте преподавателю, что он ничего не понимает в хэш-таблицах. Использование последовательных `int` в качестве ключа в словаре приводит к очень неэффективному использованию словаря, потому что `Int32.GetHashCode() => return this;`, а для эффективного использования хэш-таблицы требуется равномерное распределение значений хэшей по всему множеству значений `Int32`. Однако, возможно, вам нужен не словарь, а простой список и индексы в нём. На подобных "словарях" вы только проигрываете в производительности.

Comment: @Athari спасибо за информацию ! Но все же вопрос об удалении не раскрыт :(

Comment: @kxxko У вас модель не соответствует её использованию ни в логике программы, ни в пользовательском интерфейсе. С такой конструкцией вам нужно держать отдельный список индексов, что уже попахивает маразмом. Если вам требуются именно такие словари, и вы ничего не напутали, то передайте преподавателю, чтобы он перестал преподавать.

Comment: @Athari а как бы вы решили этот вопрос ? Где и в чем поменять логику ?

Comment: @kxxko: Тогда расскажите нам в точности свои требования. И да, преподаватель должен по крайней мере мотивировать свой дизайн, а не продавливать его.

Comment: @kxxko: Опишите операции, которые нужны, и какие инварианты мы хотим поддерживать.

Comment: @VladD Нужно создать переводчик слов (при помощи Dictionary). Проходим коллекции. 
В приложении должна быть возможность просмотра перевода (уже нескольких записанных слов с переводом), добавление новых слов и перевода к нему, редактирование, удаление перевода и поиск. Вот требования к заданию. Начал переделывать по Вашему совету <string, string> только это не поможет мне в дальнейшей удалить из Dictionary запись (так как я понимаю). Я новичок и хочу учиться, поэтому и обратился к Вам, специалистам за помощью.

Comment: @kxxko Положим, требования: быстрый поиск, отображение алфавитного списка, добавление, удаление, ручная обработка GUI. Делаем класс словарной статьи, кладём в `SortedList` с `Comparer`, который сортирует по исходному слову. Это даёт бинарный поиск, последовательный доступ к элементам и индексы, добавление через `Add` + `IndexOfKey` + `InsertAt`, удаление через `IndexOfKey` + `Remove` + `RemoveAt`... Добавление и удаление будут не самыми шустрыми, если список очень большой, но вы до тех размеров не доберётесь. / Если список *очень* большой, то нужно список в GUI полностью виртуализировать...

Comment: Тут однако нету требования последовательных id, правильно?

Comment: @VladD Возможно, есть требование отображать последовательный список в GUI.

Comment: @Athari: отображение именно id в строки нужно в случае неоднозначности. Например, лук = onion и лук = longbow

Comment: @kxxko: А какие требования на id?

Comment: @VladD требований на ID нету никаких. Это просто я подумал, что будет лучше слова искать по ID. Видимо был не прав и Вас поставил в заблуждение. Эта программа должна очень просто выглядеть, так как мы только начали эту тему )

Comment: @VladD Я исхожу из предположения, что это словарные статьи, то есть `"лук" => "onion; longbow"`. Если нужен поиск в две стороны, причём идеально оптимизированные все операции, то это уже тривиально не решить, по-моему. Если мы добавляем два словаря в обе стороны, то как-то нужно ещё GUI отображать, чтобы пользователь мог выбрать ближайшие статьи. Из словарей в дотнете эту информацию фиг вынешь, вроде (что `Dictionary`, что `SortedDictionary`).

Comment: @Athari: Я бы сделал отдельной структурой DictionaryEntry, и построил индексы.

Answer (score 2):

А почему бы не сделать так:

```
class Entry { public string Russian; public string English; }

var all = ObservableCollection<Entry>(); // для автообновления UI
```

Если нужен поиск, вы можете построить индексы:

```
var russianToEntries = Dictionary<string, List<Entry>>();
var englishToEntries = Dictionary<string, List<Entry>>();
```

Теперь для показа можно использовать список. Вам, по идее, нужно уметь сортировать список по английским и по русским ключам.

Для добавления вам надо добавить в список и в оба индекса. То же при удалении. Поиск с индексами должен быть достаточно быстрым.

Comment: Как в вашем решении отобразить соседние статьи? Например, я выбрал "doing" и хочу, чтобы сверху в списке отобразился "do", а снизу "done".

Comment: Конечно, индексы съедят много памяти, т. к. список списков. Можно подцепить вместо него MultiDictionary, по идее.

Comment: @Athari: ListView умеет сортировать по полям.

Comment: @Athari: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745786%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Какой ListView? WPF? WinForms? Как будете обновлять в нём данные?

Comment: @Athari: WPF по идее. А что, WinForms ещё не умер?

Comment: @Athari: По идее, сортировка — это задача View, не модели.

Comment: Не думаю, что простых смертных учат XAML'ю. WinForms ископаемый, но очень простой для понимания. Я всегда исхожу из предположения, что студентов учат WinForms-подобному.

Comment: У вас два словаря. Не `ObservableCollection`. Как вы будете всё синхронизировать?

Comment: @Athari: Не знаю, достаточно гибок ли view на WinForms, чтобы уметь сортироваться. Должен, по идее, это всё равно его функциональность.

Comment: @Athari: Ну да, вместо `List<Entry>` в VM надо `ObservableCollection<EntryVM>`. Поскольку у автора всё равно M и VM будут совпадать, перепишу на `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Вы из-за ObservableCollection убьёте всю производительность. Вот запросил я слово "do". Как вы сфокусируете нужный элемент? O(n). Как удалить? O(n). Добавить? O(n). А если сортировку подарить гую, то и того больше.

Comment: @Athari: Я свалил в чат, но почему-то этого тут не видно. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23476/discussion-between-athari-and-vladd

Comment: @VladD уважаемые вы мои. Я только как почти что год как программирую, и читая ваши комментарии меня бросает в холодный пот. Задание супер мега простое. Если идет речь об добавлении, то Directonary<string, string> mew = new Directoonary<string, string>(); mew.Add(); если речь идет об удалении то mew.Remove(); ничего не надо выдумывать. Я тодько начинаю программировать !

Comment: @kxxko: Не обращайте внимания :) Мы обсуждаем крайние (но интересные) случаи, в которых данных _очень_ много. От вас рассмотрения этих случаев не потребуют.

Comment: @kxxko: Вы ещё комментарии в чате не видели :) (ссылка чуть выше)

Comment: @VladD в том то и дело, что видел :) надеюсь и я когда нибудь смогу обсуждать такие темы.

Comment: @kxxko: Через год-два практики. :)

Comment: @kxxko В общем, вот вывод: хватит `ObservableCollection<T>` или `BindingList<T>` (смотря какой GUI вы используете). Всё остальное для красоты. :)

Comment: @VladD В общем выход один ! Я начну чтение книги с этой темы с самого начала и более углубленно, а приложение отдам через неделю. Лучше сделаю грамотно, чем так, как пытался. Очень был бы рад с Вами поддерживать контакт ! (Только не знаю как) =)
Спасибо огромное !

Comment: @kxxko: Очень просто: задавайте вопросы на сайте. @Athari и я обычно отвечаем по теме C#.`

Comment: @VladD а как мне можно с вопросом написать в личку ? Для общего вопроса наверное не сойдет просто :) напишите на e-mail nikto92@ya.ru ;) буду очень признателен.

Comment: @kxxko: Заходите лучше в чат: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23501/kxxko-and-vladd

Comment: @VladD можете еще раз создать чат ?) появились вопросики ! xD

Comment: @kxxko: Открыл новую: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24318/kxxko-and-vladd